# How to design a dynamic cardView in android such that two cardViews are adjacent to one another?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement cardView in android, such that two cards lay adjacent to one another as shown in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozH8L.png)

However, [I am following this tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/recyclerview-cardview/part-1-layouts-model-class). The problem with this tutorial is that in this, each row contains a single cardView element; but I need two cardViews adjacent to one another. What change should I make in the code such that two cardViews are adjacent to one another instead of one.

I am adding the cardViews dynamically. That is there is no fixed size for the number of cardViews.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD2t75T5RdY have a look at this. This might help you with what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In the Activity Main onCreate change

```
mLayoutManaget = new LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

to

```
mLayoutManaget = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
```

where 2 is the Number of Columns

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a RecyclerView (a list) of CardViews... presented in the default RecyclerView layout manager: [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html).

What you should do instead, is try using the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) and provide 2 columns.

You can check your XML to see if you have it defined there (if so, just remove it) and do it in code with something like:

`yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));`

You get the idea (I hope).